# Matplotlib: How to save a figure as a full screen image while displaying it onscreen as regular size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing a script that generates various plots and automatically saves them as image files while also displaying the plots on screen.  I'd prefer that the files save as full screen images while the pop-up plots are displayed "normal" sized.

an example of one of several attempts that i made (Note:  I'm not sure if i broke this example when i stripped out the details from my actual code):

```
  plt.figure("Example figure")
  plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
  
  # Enlarge plot to full screen for saving....
  mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
  mng.window.showMaximized()
  plt.savefig('example.png')

  # Resize plot to default size for showing....
  plt.figure("Example figure", figsize=[6.4, 4.8])
  plt.show()
```

However, this just results in the figure appearing as full-screen in both the saved file and in the shown plot.  How do i get it back into a normal window for the "show"?

Answer (score 0):

The method you use to maximise the window size depends on which matplotlib backend you are using. Please see the following example for the 3 most common backends:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,2], [1,2])

# Option 1
# QT backend
manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
manager.window.showMaximized()

# Option 2
# TkAgg backend
manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
manager.resize(*manager.window.maxsize())

# Option 3
# WX backend
manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
manager.frame.Maximize(True)

plt.show()
plt.savefig('sampleFileName.png')
```

You can determine which backend you are using with the command `matplotlib.get_backend()`. When you save the maximized version of the figure it will save a larger image as desired.

Comment: I'm using the QT backend.  The example shown is what i used to save as full-screen, however, this doesn't "show" as a regular-sized plot.  the displayed plot is full screen as well.

Comment: You have to use ```plt.savefig("name.png") ```for saving it as full screen.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand my question and comment.  I want 2 things to happen.  I want to save a plot as full screen, which i can do just fine.  Secondly, when the plot is displayed on screen, i ***do not*** want it to appear as full screen.